# Does Tuxedo XA transaction manager support ActiveMQ as resource manager for C++ applications?

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, xa, activemq-cpp, tuxedo

I am looking for examples or resources to prove support for ActiveMQ as one of the resource managers with Tuxedo as the XA transaction manager. I am working on building a C++ Application to do the same. I am unable to find any documentation on Tuxedo community or Google for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not support it out of the box. There is a list of resource managers supported in $TUXDIR/udataobj/RM. To support ActiveMQ, you should add an entry in the RM file with the resource manager name, a symbol name that contains pointers to XA functions, and a list of libraries for linking the resource manager. After that, you should be able to build a transaction manager server, see the manual for buildtms command.

Comment: thanks, are you aware if there is already a library available from ActiveMQ which has XA functions , so that i can plug it in and run buildtms?

Comment: There are classes in the [ActiveMQ CMS client](https://activemq.apache.org/components/cms/) that provide XA functions. See `ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory`, `ActiveMQXAConnection`, and `ActiveMQXASession`. `ActiveMQXASession` in particular provides `getXAResource()` which returns an `XAResource`.

Comment: do we have XA switch functions library provided by ActiveMQ , which can be setup in $TUXDIR/udataobj/RM ?